# Kafka Connect not logging my Connector Logs

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j, apache-kafka-connect

I wrote a custom Kafka Source Connector. I wanted to test the connector, so I copied the uber JAR to the `${CONFLUENT_HOME}/share/java` location and placed the configurations (`connect-standalone.properties` and `connect-file-source.properties`) in the etc location under a directory I created for my connector.

When I tried to start the connector as follows:

`$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/connect-standalone $CONFLUENT_HOME/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties $CONFLUENT_HOME/etc/kafka/connect-file-source.properties`

I tried to run my connector. It starts and produces the records to Kafka. But, I don't see my connector logs anywhere. I tried with adding my connector's log4j.properties and also tried to update the connect-log4j.properties. Still I don't see my logs.

For ex: I have a log statement as such:

```
@Override
public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
    log.info("*** Start Method called ***");

    filename = props.get(FileStreamTailerSourceConnector.FILE_CONFIG);
```

Below is a snippet of my `connect-file-source.properties` file.

```
name=kafka-connect-file
connector.class=com.connect.file.FileStreamTailerSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

#Path to where the file is going to be published.
file=test_data.csv

# Topic to publish file data to.
# MANDATORY FIELD, no default
# Valid Values: non-empty string and no ISO control characters
topic=tailer_test2

# Window of data to pull from log api.
# Valid Values: [2,...,10000]
# The default is 100.
batch.size=2

# Poll interval in milliseconds. E.G. Roughly, how often the connector will connect to the file and read data.
# The default is 1000 as in once a second.
poll.interval=1000

# Schema file for the records of the file
source.schema=test_data_schema.avsc

# Encryption of fields in the record for security
field.encryption=true
encryption.fields=bin,ssn,acn
encryption.class=com.connect.encryption.DummyEncryption
```

Below is my snippet of `connect-standalone.properties`:

```
# A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.
bootstrap.servers=<LIST OF COMMA SEPARATED BOOTSTRAP SERVERS>

# unique name for the cluster, used in forming the Connect cluster group. Note that this must not conflict with consumer group IDs
group.id=connect-cluster-file-test1

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets-test1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1

config.storage.topic=connect-configs-test1
config.storage.replication.factor=1

status.storage.topic=connect-status-test1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
#status.storage.partitions=5

# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

rest.port=8083


plugin.path=/share/confluent/package/share/java
```

I don't see the above log message anywhere. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are u using Confluent Platform? If so use the command: confluent local load <name your connector > -- -d <path to your connect-file-source.properties file>

Comment: Yes, I'm using confluent platform. As I mentioned in the comment below, I tried that and was able to start my connector.. but not able to locate/print the connector's logs.

Comment: Can u share your connect-file-source.properties file? And also your standalone properties !!

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: How does your code compare to https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir OR https://github.com/mmolimar/kafka-connect-fs or Why not use something like Fluentbit / Fluentd / Filebeat / Flume which all offer Kafka solutions for log tailing?

Comment: Codewise, it looks very similar. Except that the spooldir has a lot of abstractions around the implementation.

The main idea was to build a POC using Kafka Connect to explore its capabilities.

Comment: You can build a POC using the ones I listed.... But if you seriously want to read files, use Filebeat, Logstash, Flume, Fluentd / Fluentbit... Then research just the ELK stack and use Kafka Connect ElasticSink, if you want